# onSingleTapConfirmed() being raised after onDoubleTap()

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am faced with the problem described in the title and was wondering am I doing something wrong or this is another android glitch. Here is a little bit more about problem in question:
I have a view with image that supports double tap to zoom and pinch to zoom but would like to use single short tap to show image title in action bar (actually call getActionBar().show() and hide()). Also the views with images are in ViewPager (found in support library v4). I am currently doing the following things:
In the viewpager I do this in order to stop page change when zooming by pinch to zoom:

```
// view in the fragment is a reference to MyZoomableImageView
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 currentFragment.view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
             if (currentFragment.view.downloaded && (!currentFragment.view.whole || event.getPointerCount() > 1)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
```

And in my customImageView I add gesture detector with a this listener:

```
public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DOUBLE");
        zoom();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SINGLE");
            Activity a = ((Activity) context);
            ActionBar action = a.getActionBar();
            if (action.isShowing()) {
                action.hide();
            } else {
                action.show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong and why are both SINGE and DOUBLE massages logged after double tap.

PS.I did kind of solved this with using a time difference between event listeners calls something like if (!((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 500)) but this just feels wrong and I guess there is a proper way to do this.

Comment: (I'm aware this is an ancient issue.) This is happening likely because of how/where you call [GestureDetector#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)); if, e.g. it receives the same touch event twice you will get the issue you describe. Could you post the part of your code where you use your GestureListener?

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, and this needs to be confirmed. However, `OnSingleTapConfirmed()` is only consumed once android is positive that the single tap has occured, (often times this takes a while). I would think that using `OnSingleTapUp()` would work better.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

> public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
>
> Notified when a single-tap occurs.
>
> Unlike onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent), this will only be called after the
>   detector is confident that the user's first tap is not followed by a
>   second tap leading to a double-tap gesture.

Comment: Well I did used the onSingleTapUp first but found out that it is called two times when double tap is executed and than read "Unlike onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent), this will only be called after the detector is confident that the user's first tap is not followed by a second tap leading to a double-tap gesture."

Comment: So I think the purpose of the onSingleTapUp is just what I need because it shouldn't be called if double tap was detected.

Comment: Ah I see. One more thing to try though, OnDoubleTapEvent(). Not sure if this would work, but it would appear that it should be consumed more quickly.

Comment: What should be "one more thing to try" could you please be more precise?

Comment: I would try replacing OnDoubleTap() with OnDoubleTapEvent(), as it should be consumed more quickly.

Comment: I just tried it and same thing happens (both double and single are raised) but thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have

> Settings / Accessibility / Magnification Gestures

turned on? When those are turned on, double taps will (in most cases) be reported as onSingleTapConfirmed(). See also this bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185872